# Run a countdown timer from the array in sequence

Tags: python

I have an array that has values ​​representing the number of seconds green in the traffic light for a specific intersection, I want the countdown to start from the first value and then move to the next value, and after the end of the last value the process is restarted again, giving the value of red and waiting for each intersection.

```
array=[20,10,15,30]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `time.sleep()` to have the process wait for T seconds (for each T in `times`) inside an infinite loop.

```py
import time

times = [20, 10, 15, 30]
while True: # Runs until you terminate the process
    for i in range(len(times)): 
        print("Light {} is green.".format(i+1))
        time.sleep(times[i])
```

The cycle would print out:

```
Light 1 is green.

# 20 seconds later
Light 2 is green.

# 10 seconds later
Light 3 is green.

# 15 seconds later
Light 4 is green

# 30 seconds later 
Light 1 is green

# And repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that will get the array and will wait for the time:

```
import time
def countdown(array):
    for i in array:
        #Go from up down 3,2,1
        for seconds in range(i, 0, -1):
            print("Green")
            #Sleep for a second
            time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to block your processes with time.sleep you can create a function that prints the green light regardless of how much time has elapsed.

```
import time
array=[2,5,3,3]
def timeInterval( array ):
    initTime = time.time()
    def whichLight():
        nonlocal initTime 
        dt = time.time() - initTime 
        dt = dt % sum( array )
        if dt - array[0] < 0: return [1, 0, 0, 0]
        dt -= array[0]
        if dt - array[1] < 0: return [0, 1, 0, 0]
        dt -= array[1]
        if dt - array[2] < 0: return [0, 0, 1, 0]
        else:
            return [0, 0, 0, 1]

    return whichLight
lights = timeInterval( array )
from random import randint
s = randint( 0, sum( array ) - 1 )
time.sleep( s ) #let arbitray amount of time lapse
print( f'after {s} seconds: { lights()}' )
```

You still have to continually check though if you want to catch the light right as they switch.

```
while True:
    print( lights() )
```